# How to stop Visual Studio 2010 on compilation error

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

At work we have a solution with over 90 projects. I want to know if there is a way to stop visual studio from compiling as soon as it encounters an error. Normally it will compile as far as it can and show a list of errors in the error window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to break compilation as part of an automated build process or just manually?

Answer (score 13):

There is an extension for Visual Studio 2010 - 2017 for this purpose by Einar Egilsson:
http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2011/01/06/stop-build-on-first-error-in-visual-studio-2010/

> StopOnFirstBuildError is Visual Studio 2010 extension that cancels the rest of a solution build if a single project fails to compile, thus saving you time. [Download it in the Visual Studio Gallery.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/91aaa139-5d3c-43a7-b39f-369196a84fa5/)

Comment: This is the most elegant solution!

Comment: Just noting Einar updated this for VS 2013 and VS 2015.

Answer (score 3):

Try VSCommands [http://vscommands.com/feature-comparison](http://vscommands.com/feature-comparison/) the free (lite) version includes this feature (among others).

Comment: Nice find.  For just breaking on error, Sergii Volchkov's answer is best, but this has some neat stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Default Shortcut for C#: CTRL+BREAK

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to find this shortcut. Not sure I can vote the answer up as it doesn't strictly answer the question, but it answered *my* question :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can always hit the break key to manually stop the compile.